# Android service and utils package

Tags: android, service, package

When I develep an android app, what should I put in utils package and same question for service package?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Um, whatever you want.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, tnx. Btw I learned a lot form ur books. :)